# Canvas background image?

Tags: canvas, background

Sorry for my bad English, but could anybody told me how to add background image instead of only black color to this

[Canvas with moouse effect](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/html5-canvas-experiment-a-cool-flame-fire-effect-using-particles)

I have tried with css but no success

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012768/html5-canvas-background-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load image on top of javascript

```
var background = new Image();
background.src = "http://127.0.0.1/bg.jpg";
```

then replace lines

```
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
```

with

```
ctx.drawImage(background,0,0);
```

Comment: Yes! :D Thank you very much, it shows effect good on image, with little tweaking it will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

1 add image to html body tag

```
<BODY background='http://127.0.0.1/bg.jpg'>
```

2 remove these lines from javascript

```
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
```

Comment: This somehow works but not completely :) Background is good but effect not, it leaves effect on whole image when you move mouse, i dont know how to say, mouse trail stays on backgorund. I will try to tweak xD Maybe, if i could make canvas transparent

edit: tried to make canvas transparent, then effect dont show