# Is it possible to add a background image to a plot in vega or vega-lite?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I see from https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html that it is possible to change the background color.  But i don't see any docs for adding an underlay background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vega-lite creates a canvas element.

So adding a background image is explained in a question about how to add a background to a canvas element.

[HTML5 Canvas background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012768/html5-canvas-background-image)

But you can just do it with css:

```
canvas {
  background: url("my_background.png");
}
```

This is just like any other background image css.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Comment: where to put that  canvas background  configuration in a vega config ?

Comment: @user47950, you might want to do some research on CSS.  This is not a part of the vega config.  If you aren't familiar with developing web pages, you might want to find a primer on HTML, CSS, and javascript.