# How to add background image to vega/vegalite canvas and include in export PNG

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have a similar question as [Bob Baxley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5058588/bob-baxley) had in [Is it possible to add a background image to a plot in vega or vega-lite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580080/is-it-possible-to-add-a-background-image-to-a-plot-in-vega-or-vega-lite/49583424#49583424)

Adding the image using CSS does not include it in the actual canvas. While it looks good it will not be exported via the "export as PNG" action.
Trying the option of using `.drawImage()` on the canvas does work in so far that the image is then displayed, however the PNG export still doesn't embed the image.

The approach I used:

```
    // GET THE IMAGE.
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'img/myimage.png';

    // WAIT TILL IMAGE IS LOADED.
    img.onload = function () {
        fill_canvas(img); 
    }
    function fill_canvas(img) {
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName()[0];
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Results look good, but using the "Export as PNG" action only gives me the original chart without the added image.
So how can I properly add a watermark/background image?

Answer (score 0):

The PNG output only processes the content of the Vega/Vega-Lite specification, so in order for the image to be included in that output, the image has to be part of the specification.

Unfortunately, there is no mechanism to include images in Vega-Lite specifications, as of the current version (2.6).

There is, howerver, a mechanism to include images in a Vega specification, via the Image mark; you can see an example here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/image/ You could use this approach to add a background image within a vega chart.