# Why I don't get an image drawn on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

No errors, nothing. But the image still don't show up. When I `console.log(background);` I see the src of the image in the console, like so `<img src="ground.png">`. Here is the code:

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pirate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="240"></canvas>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var StyleSheet = function(image, width, height) {
  this.image = image;
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;

  this.draw = function(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height) {
    context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height);
  }
}

var Loader = function(src) {
  this.image = new Image();
  this.image.src = src;
  return this.image;
}

var background = new Loader("ground.png");
console.log(background);
var sprite = new StyleSheet(background, 50, 50);
  sprite.draw(background, 0, 0, 16, 16, 0, 0, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Please add your Html code in snippet

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Edited

Comment: @Loktar https://stackoverflow.com/a/14013068/4040563

Comment: @Thomas https://stackoverflow.com/a/6011402/4040563

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try should call draw on image onload event something like below

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var StyleSheet = function(image, width, height) {
   this.image = image;
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;

   this.draw = function(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height) {
  image.onload = function(){
   context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, x, y, width, height);
  }
  
   }
 }

 var Loader = function(src) {
   this.image = new Image();
   this.image.src = src;
   return this.image;
 }

 var background = new Loader("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/902653914465550336/QE3287ZJ_400x400.jpg");
 console.log(background);
 var sprite = new StyleSheet(background, 50, 50);
   sprite.draw(background, 0, 0, 16, 16, 0, 0, 50, 50);
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="240" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)