# Change the background of canvas element to url

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So what I want to do is I want to change the HTML line of code from

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" class="canvas"></canvas>
```

to have a style attribute added to look like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" class="canvas" style="background: url(SOMEURL);"></canvas>
```

The JavaScript I have tried is this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Then inside a function That I call after 4 seconds I have:

```
canvas.style.backgroundImage =
'url(data:image/png;base64,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);';
```

But after the line of code gets run it now looks like:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" class="canvas" style=""></canvas>
```

The style is just blank. What I am I doing wrong? Thanks. Will pick the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012768/html5-canvas-background-image

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Thanks for showing me that but I don't want to draw the image onto the canvas because I have to be able to draw it and draw on top of that again. So I need it to be done via styling. thanks for the suggestion though. If I drawImage then I can't draw an image on top of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery for that and set the background property to desired url of your canvas element. In your case, a base64 image. Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#canvas').css('background',"url(data:image/png;base64,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)");
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500" class="canvas" style="background: url('https://i.imgur.com/FUsyxR5.jpg');"></canvas>
```