# How to find and replace color in canvas for image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, colors

I have use fabric js and set one canvas with background image.
Now i want to change color of image that i have set in my canvas background.
For example Image with 3 different colors. but i want change only one color area and invert another color.

It's Possible to do with canvas ? and How ? if any knows pls help me

My Level as learner in canvas and javascripts.

My Code is here.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imagesection');
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').click(function(){
      getImagebg();
   });
});

function getImagebg()
{
   var source = $('a.view-link.active').attr('data-src');  
   var image = new Image();
   image.onload = function () { 
     canvas.setWidth(image.width);
     canvas.setHeight(image.height);
     canvas.setBackgroundImage(f_img);
     canvas.renderAll();
     var f_img = new fabric.Image(image);
     canvas.setBackgroundImage(f_img);
     canvas.renderAll();
  }
  image.src = source;
}

/*For Change Color of image section*/
$('#colorchange').click(function(){
   ChangeColor();
});
function ChangeColor(){
  /*Change Color code sholud be like this.*/
}
```

Old
[Before change colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Anm.png)
New
[After change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj1GU.png)

Comment: as the matter of "is it Possible", answer is "Yes". But if you want to ask us how is it possible then please also tell us how are you already doing this by providing you code etc

Comment: Have you tried the canvas fillStyle property ?

Comment: @AnsBilal i have tried like this : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4apAS/)

Comment: Can your create your fiddle code so that we can see and test your code there

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link might help it uses the same technique you are using

[link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012768/html5-canvas-background-image)